# sql server + vb 6.0

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000

I have created one database project in vb 6.0.  I have created my database in sql server 2000.  I am using adodc and odbc to connect to database.

I want to keep my sql server in one system and my vb 6.0 application in another system and I want to access sql database from network.

Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? What you mentioned is absolutely achievable provided you code towards that.

Comment: Surely you mean OLEDB and not ODBC?  Maybe see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server#p6

Comment: Bonus points for still writing new apps in VB6 and SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I still write new apps in VB6 with SQL Server 2000 and/or 2005. Corporate environment still uses it here. :)

Comment: I still maintain our legacy VB6 projects as well

Answer (score 1):

This is how many client applications are written: A VB6 program running on a desktop system, and the SQL Server running on another system, usually on a Windows Server OS.

As long as you have a reference in your VB6 program to Microsoft ADO, and you set up your connection string properly, there shouldn't be an issue.

Please add more detail to your question if this doesn't point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Class, cDatabase, I use to use to access a MS SQL database using an ODBC DSN Connection:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_eDBCursorType As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum  'Cursor (Dynamic, Forward Only, Keyset, Static)
Private m_eDBLockType As ADODB.LockTypeEnum    'Locks (BatchOptimistic,Optimistic,Pessimistic, Read Only)
Private m_eDBOptions As ADODB.CommandTypeEnum 'DB Options
Private m_sDSNName As String
Private m_sSQLUserID As String
Private m_sSQLPassword As String
Private cn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_eDBCursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    m_eDBLockType = adLockReadOnly
    m_eDBOptions = adCmdText
End Sub

Private Function ConnectionString() As String

    ConnectionString = "DSN=" & m_sDSNName & "" & _
                            ";UID=" & m_sSQLUserID & _
                            ";PWD=" & m_sSQLPassword & ";"

End Function

Private Sub GetCN()
On Error GoTo GetCN_Error

If cn.State = 0 Then
StartCN:
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open ConnectionString

    With cn
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    End With
End If


On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

GetCN_Error:
If Err.Number = 91 Then
    Resume StartCN
Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure GetCN of Module modDatabaseConnections"
End If

End Sub

Public Function GetRS(sSQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset

Dim eRS As ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo GetRS_Error

TryAgain:

If Len(Trim(sSQL)) > 0 Then
    Call GetCN

    Set eRS = New ADODB.Recordset       'Creates record set
    eRS.Open sSQL, cn, m_eDBCursorType, m_eDBLockType, m_eDBOptions
    Set GetRS = eRS

Else
    MsgBox "You have to submit a SQL String"
End If

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

GetRS_Error:
If Err.Number = 91 Then
    Call GetCN
    GoTo TryAgain
ElseIf Err.Number = -2147217900 Then
    Exit Function
Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure GetRS of Module" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "SQL - " & sSQL
End If

End Function

Public Property Get DBOptions() As ADODB.CommandTypeEnum

    DBOptions = m_eDBOptions

End Property

Public Property Let DBOptions(ByVal eDBOptions As ADODB.CommandTypeEnum)

    m_eDBOptions = eDBOptions

End Property

Public Property Get DBCursorType() As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum

    DBCursorType = m_eDBCursorType

End Property

Public Property Let DBCursorType(ByVal eDBCursorType As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum)

    m_eDBCursorType = eDBCursorType

End Property

Public Property Get DBLockType() As ADODB.LockTypeEnum

    DBLockType = m_eDBLockType

End Property

Public Property Let DBLockType(ByVal eDBLockType As ADODB.LockTypeEnum)

    m_eDBLockType = eDBLockType

End Property

Public Property Get DSNName() As String

    DSNName = m_sDSNName

End Property

Public Property Let DSNName(ByVal sDSNName As String)

    m_sDSNName = sDSNName

End Property

Public Property Get SQLUserID() As String

    SQLUserID = m_sSQLUserID

End Property

Public Property Let SQLUserID(ByVal sSQLUserID As String)

    m_sSQLUserID = sSQLUserID

End Property

Public Property Get SQLPassword() As String

    SQLPassword = m_sSQLPassword

End Property

Public Property Let SQLPassword(ByVal sSQLPassword As String)

    m_sSQLPassword = sSQLPassword

End Property
```

and here is how I instantiated and called it:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim DB As cDatabase
Dim l As Long

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set DB = New cDatabase

    With DB
        .DBCursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .DBLockType = adLockReadOnly
        .DBOptions = adCmdText
        .DSNName = "Your_DSN_Name"
        .SQLUserID = "Your_SQL_Login_Name"
        .SQLPassword = "Your_SQL_Login_Password"
        Set rs = .GetRS("Select Field1 FROM Table1")
    End With

    If rs.RecordCount <= 0 Then Goto Exit_Sub

    For l = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        Debug.Print rs(0).Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Next l

Exit_Sub:
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Also make sure that you add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.X Library