# VB6.0 with DataControl Database Programming

Tags: vb6

can you help out access the database... I have been reading some tutorials but I don't know where to start doing this one. I used DataControl to access the database. First, the program will prompt for the ID Number and then Search for the further information and display it in texboxes when **Search Employee** button clicked. I know how to set the properties of textboxes in order to appear the value of my database to my output without clicking the **Search Employee** button but I want to click first the button **Search Employee**. I'm a beginner in VB6. Please help me out! I need this project now.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you mind asking you for a favor? Kindly give me some sites of Tutorial where I could study this VB6. Actually, I've been looking through a bunch of sites, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find a tutorial I needed. I need Simple DataEntry, Search, Edit, Delete, and View programs using DataControl and not Adodc.I found www.vb6.us, there I learnt to connect by modifying the properties of textboxes as well as DataControl, by that, the values of my database are automatically appearing in the textboxes, and that isn’t what I mean.

Comment: I have a textbox, and this is a required field for the IDNumber(index), and there is also a Command Button, whenever you click it, the IDNumber that has been entered into the textbox will look for its further information(Name, Address, ContactNumber) in the database and will be displayed in the textboxes respectively. Please help me out! ...wait for your response. Thanks loads!

Comment: Here you go: [Site1](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Visual-Basic/Implementing-An-ADO-Data-Control-With-VB6/) and [Site2](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~saul/vb_examples/tutorial4/index.html). I think you maybe better off using ADO to access your data, take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482093/sql-server-vb-6-0/5488106#5488106), as it will illustrate how you can access your data via ADO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I had some time to spare, here you go, first add a reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.X Library**:

Form1 Code:

```
Option Explicit
''Add the following items to your form and name them as indicated:
''Four(4) text boxes - Named: tbIDNumber, tbName, tbAddress, and tbContactName.
''One(1) Command button - Named Command1

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim DB As cDatabase
Dim l As Long

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set DB = New cDatabase

    With DB
        .DBCursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .DBLockType = adLockReadOnly
        .DBOptions = adCmdText
        .DSNName = "Your_DSN_Name"
        .SQLUserID = "Your_SQL_Login_Name"
        .SQLPassword = "Your_SQL_Login_Password"
        Set rs = .GetRS("Select Name, Address, ContactNumber FROM YourTableName WHERE IDNumber = '" & tbIDNumber.Text & "'")
    End With

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        tbName.Text = rs(0).Value & ""
        tbAddress.Text = rs(1).Value & ""
        tbContactName.Text = rs(2).Value & ""
    End If

Exit_Sub:
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Add a Class Module Object to your project and name it **cDatabase**. Then copy the following Code into it:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_eDBCursorType As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum  'Cursor (Dynamic, Forward Only, Keyset, Static)
Private m_eDBLockType As ADODB.LockTypeEnum    'Locks (BatchOptimistic,Optimistic,Pessimistic, Read Only)
Private m_eDBOptions As ADODB.CommandTypeEnum 'DB Options
Private m_sDSNName As String
Private m_sSQLUserID As String
Private m_sSQLPassword As String
Private cn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_eDBCursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    m_eDBLockType = adLockReadOnly
    m_eDBOptions = adCmdText
End Sub

Private Function ConnectionString() As String

    ConnectionString = "DSN=" & m_sDSNName & "" & _
                            ";UID=" & m_sSQLUserID & _
                            ";PWD=" & m_sSQLPassword & ";"
''If you are using MS Access as your back end you will need to change the connection string to the following:
     ''ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _

''If you are using a DNS-Less connection to SQL Server, then you will need to change the connection string to the following:
     ''ConnectionString = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=" & m_sSQLUserID & ";Password=" & m_sSQLPassword & ";"

''You can find more Connection Strings at http://connectionstrings.com/

End Function

Private Sub GetCN()
On Error GoTo GetCN_Error

If cn.State = 0 Then
StartCN:
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open ConnectionString

    With cn
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    End With
End If


On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

GetCN_Error:
If Err.Number = 91 Then
    Resume StartCN
Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure GetCN of Module modDatabaseConnections"
End If

End Sub

Public Function GetRS(sSQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset

Dim eRS As ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo GetRS_Error

TryAgain:

If Len(Trim(sSQL)) > 0 Then
    Call GetCN

    Set eRS = New ADODB.Recordset       'Creates record set
    eRS.Open sSQL, cn, m_eDBCursorType, m_eDBLockType, m_eDBOptions
    Set GetRS = eRS

Else
    MsgBox "You have to submit a SQL String"
End If

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

GetRS_Error:
If Err.Number = 91 Then
    Call GetCN
    GoTo TryAgain
ElseIf Err.Number = -2147217900 Then
    Exit Function
Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure GetRS of Module" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "SQL - " & sSQL
End If

End Function

Public Property Get DBOptions() As ADODB.CommandTypeEnum

    DBOptions = m_eDBOptions

End Property

Public Property Let DBOptions(ByVal eDBOptions As ADODB.CommandTypeEnum)

    m_eDBOptions = eDBOptions

End Property

Public Property Get DBCursorType() As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum

    DBCursorType = m_eDBCursorType

End Property

Public Property Let DBCursorType(ByVal eDBCursorType As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum)

    m_eDBCursorType = eDBCursorType

End Property

Public Property Get DBLockType() As ADODB.LockTypeEnum

    DBLockType = m_eDBLockType

End Property

Public Property Let DBLockType(ByVal eDBLockType As ADODB.LockTypeEnum)

    m_eDBLockType = eDBLockType

End Property

Public Property Get DSNName() As String

    DSNName = m_sDSNName

End Property

Public Property Let DSNName(ByVal sDSNName As String)

    m_sDSNName = sDSNName

End Property

Public Property Get SQLUserID() As String

    SQLUserID = m_sSQLUserID

End Property

Public Property Let SQLUserID(ByVal sSQLUserID As String)

    m_sSQLUserID = sSQLUserID

End Property

Public Property Get SQLPassword() As String

    SQLPassword = m_sSQLPassword

End Property

Public Property Let SQLPassword(ByVal sSQLPassword As String)

    m_sSQLPassword = sSQLPassword

End Property
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks loads for the code, but I think that's for those intermediate programmers. Can you help me make a program using VB6? I want to get the hang of your codes. Please help me out! I'm a beginner programmer.

Comment: How can I contact you? please I need your help, I have an account on Skype, here's my skype name: aaronarela.... and also my gmail eadd: aerohn.arela@gmail.com

Comment: I just sent you a sample project file via web site called Stream File. You will need to edit the code to include the name of your DSN as well as the User Name and Password. BTW, here is the [LINK](http://www.streamfile.com/myid/7UFYgua4qZ7Q) to the file, just in case you didn't receive the email. I hope this helps!

Comment: It is a [class](http://edais.mvps.org/Tutorials/Classes/index.html) that is instantiated in the Command1_Click event

Comment: Sir can you give me a very simple code using ADODB? I used to use DataControl and I've no background with this kind of code. Please sir! Thank you very much for your effort...

Comment: or much better, separate the search, add, delete, view and edit with a simple code. Thanks in advance!